# Starting BCP from T-SQL: handling quotes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I am trying to run the following command from SSMS:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT *  FROM [erpSQL].[dbo].[Documents]  WHERE NoDoc like 'F%' and DateDoc = cast(GETDATE() as DATE)" queryout "d:\test.txt" -c -t -T '
```

and of course I have an error with `like 'F%'`, saying `Incorrect syntax near 'F'`.
How do I handle that ?
I tried doubling the single quotes, but it's not that.
I tried using doubles quotes instead, that gives me an `error near AND`.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `'F%'` paramenter. You can do this by adding anoter ' at the begining and the end of your current parameter, like this `''F%''`.

Comment: That was it. I thought I had tried this, but apparently not correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Retry to use the escape sequence for single quote:

```
WHERE NoDoc like ''F%''
```

It must work!